# How to add multiple logos in Bootstrap navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add two logos to my bootstrap navbar, but I also want them to be responsive (i.e. I want them to get smaller, not stacked when I decrease the screen size). Here's the navbar code I have been working on-

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                  <img alt="Brand" id="brand1" src="img/image.png">
              </a>

              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                  <img alt="Brand" id="brand2" src="img/image2.png">
              </a>

          </div>
      </div>
  </nav>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How you need exactly, give code-pen or fiddle example to understand better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created the example of having two logo side by side.

Please check the working example at **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/gwbBrm?editors=1100)**

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="nav-header">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img alt="Brand" id="brand2" src="http://www.kratosuk.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/joomla-logo.png" class="img img-responsive">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">

              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img alt="Brand" id="brand1" class="img img-responsive" src="http://www.kratosuk.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/drupal-logo.png">
              </a>


            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-brand {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I hope it helps you

Enjoy :)

Comment: One more thing, do you know how can I place them in the centre? Sorry I am new to CSS :(

Comment: This seems a bit overcomplicated.. Check out [this fork I made](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/awJwOv) as a possible alternative

Answer (score 0):

The 'img-reponsive' class should help you.

```
<img alt="Brand" id="brand1" src="img/image.png" class="img-responsive">
```

Hope it helped you :)